# Prove that $S$ is similar to $T$ by finding a basis where $S \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

-> The linear operator $T$ is defined as $T(a_n)=0$ and $T(a_i)=a_{i+1}$ where ${a_1,a_2,...,a_n}$ are basis vectors

So I found the matrix of $T$ and also from the matrix it is easy to determine that $T^n=0$.Now, $S$ is a linear operator ,such that  $S^n=0$.I need to find a basis such that $T$ and $S$ are similar.The fact that I dont know the mateix of $S$ is making things complicated.

Comment: Are $a_i$ the basis vectors? And we will need to know more about $S$, because $S=0$ fits the bill but $T$ is not similar to the zero matrix.

Comment: This might be true if we add the condition that $S^{n-1} \neq 0$

Comment: How do I proceed with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, we are given that $S^{n-1} \neq 0$ and $S^n = 0$, and we want to show that $S$ is similar to $T$.

To show that this is the case, construct a basis as follows. Because $S^{n-1} \neq 0$, there exists a vector $v$ in our vector space for which $S^{n-1}(v) \neq 0$. For this vector $v$, consider the vectors
$$
b_1 = v, \quad b_2 = T(v), \quad \dots \quad b_n = T^{n-1}(v).
$$
From there, proceed as follows:

- Show that the set $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ is linearly independent and therefore forms a basis of our vector space.
- Note that $S(b_i) = b_{i+1}$ for $i = 1,\dots,n-1$ and $S(b_n) = 0$. Use this to conclude that $S$ is similar to $T$.

Comment: why will there exist a vector V such that $S^{n-1}(v)=0$ @Omnomnomnom.what I wanted to ask why will it be $S^{n-1}$ and not $S$?

Comment: @smita That should say $S^{n-1}(v) \neq 0$